# Collapse redundant rows in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table in the format:

```
myTable <- data.table(Col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), Col2 = 1:6)
print(myTable)

   Col1 Col2
1:    A    1
2:    A    2
3:    A    3
4:    B    4
5:    B    5
6:    B    6
```

I want show only the highest result for each category in Col1, then collapse all others and present their sum in Col2. It should look like this:

```
print(myTable)

       Col1 Col2
1:        A    3
2:   Others    3
3:        B    6
4:   Others    9
```

I managed to do it with the following code:

```
unique <- unique(myTable$Col1)                                  # unique values in Col1
myTable2 <- data.table()                                        # empty data table to populate
for(each in unique){
    temp <- myTable[Col1 == each, ]                             # filter myTable for unique Col1 values
    temp <- temp[order(-Col2)]                                  # order filtered table increasingly
    sumCol2 <- sum(temp$Col2)                                   # sum of values in filtered Col2
    temp <- temp[1, ] # retain only first element
    remSum <- sumCol2 - sum(temp$Col2)                          # remaining sum in Col2 (without first element)
    temp <- rbindlist(list(temp, data.table("Others", remSum))) # rbind first element and remaining elements
    myTable2 <- rbindlist(list(myTable2, temp))                 # populate data table from beginning
}
```

This works, but I am trying to shorten a very large data table, so it takes forever.

Is there any better way to approach this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Actually my procedure is a little bit more complicated. I figured I would be able to develop it myself after the basics were mastered but it seems I will need further help instead. I want to display the 5 highest values in Col1, and collapse the others, but some entries in Col1 do not have 5 values; in these case, all entries should be displayed, and no "Others" row should be added.

Comment: `"I want show only the first result for each category in Col1"` looks like you want to show the last.

Comment: Actually I meant the highest value, corrected it, thanks.

Comment: well .... that changes everything. I updated my solution.

Comment: That is a bad format for use in analysis, since you can no longer recognize the first "Others" as associated with A except based on current sorting. Anyway, re your "update", maybe `myTable[order(-Col2), lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(Col1, r = as.character(replace(r <- rowid(Col1), r > 5, "other")))]` though you'd need to provide a relevant example so we can confirm... Since so many answers have been posted, you could post a new question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here the data is split into groups according to the value of `Col1` (`by = Col1`). `.N` is the index of the last row in the given group, so `c(Col2[.N], sum(Col2) - Col2[.N]))` gives the last value of `Col2`, and the sum of `Col2` minus the last value. The newly created variables are surrounded by `.()` because `.()` is an alias for the `list()` function when using data.table, and the  created columns need to go in a list.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, .(Col1 = c(Col1, 'Others'),
       Col2 = c(Col2[.N], sum(Col2) - Col2[.N]))
  , by = Col1][, -1]
#      Col1 Col2
# 1:      A    3
# 2: Others    3
# 3:      B    6
# 4: Others    9
```

Comment: Excellent! Do you mind explaining the syntax? Though I'm loving it, I am a beginner to the data.table package still. Actually, my procedure is a little bit more complicated: I want the retain the top 5 entries, but some values in Col1 do not have 5 entries; in these cases, all entries should be retained and no "Others" row should be included.

Answer (score 1):

If it just a matter of displaying things you could the 'tables' packages :

```
others <- function(x) sum(x)-last(x)
df %>% tabular(Col1*(last+others) ~ Col2, .)

# Col1        Col2
# A    last   3   
#      others 3   
# B    last   6   
#      others 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(
    rbind, lapply(split(myTable, factor(myTable$Col1)), function(x) rbind(x[which.max(x$Col2),], list("Other", sum(x$Col2[-which.max(x$Col2)]))))
)

#    Col1 Col2
#1:     A    3
#2: Other    3
#3:     B    6
#4: Other    9
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it! I made a new *myTable* to illustrate. I want to retain only the 4 highest values by category, and collapse the others.

```
set.seeed(123)
myTable <- data.table(Col1 = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 4)), Col2 = sample(1:12, 12))
print(myTable)

    Col1 Col2
 1:    A    8
 2:    A    5
 3:    A    2
 4:    B    7
 5:    B   10
 6:    B    9
 7:    B   12
 8:    B   11
 9:    C    4
10:    C    6
11:    C    3
12:    C    1

# set key to Col2, it will sort it increasingly
setkey(myTable, Col2)

# if there are more than 4 entries by Col1 category, will return all information, otherwise will return 4 entries completing with NA
myTable <- myTable[,.(Col2 = Col2[1:max(c(4, .N))]) , by = Col1]

# will print in Col1: 4 entries of Col1 category, then "Other"
# will print in Col2: 4 last entries of Col2 in that category, then the remaining sum 
myTable <- myTable[, .(Col1 = c(rep(Col1, 4), "Other"), Col2 = c(Col2[.N-3:0], sum(Col2) - sum(Col2[.N-3:0]))), by = Col1]

# removes rows with NA inserted in first step
myTable <- na.omit(myTable)

# removes rows where Col2 = 0, inserted because that Col1 category had exactly 4    entries
myTable <- myTable[Col2 != 0]
```

Owooooo!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution and the `dplyr` equivalent:

```
res <- aggregate(Col2 ~.,transform(
  myTable, Col0 = replace(Col1,duplicated(Col1,fromLast = TRUE), "Other")), sum)
res[order(res$Col1),-1]
#    Col0 Col2
# 1     A    3
# 3 Other    3
# 2     B    6
# 4 Other    9

myTable %>%
  group_by(Col0= Col1, Col1= replace(Col1,duplicated(Col1,fromLast = TRUE),"Other")) %>%
  summarize_at("Col2",sum) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-1)
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Col1   Col2
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 A         3
# 2 Other     3
# 3 B         6
# 4 Other     9
```